# Sine function and Wiener process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W_t$ be a Wiener process and consider the stochastic differential equation
$$dX_t = \sin(t)dW_t.$$

Is the solution to this SDE $X_t = W_t\sin(t)$?

Comment: All you need to do is check if it is a solution or not, because uniqueness comes for free from the Lipschitz nature of the coefficient. Is there some trouble while applying the Ito rule?

Comment: The increments of $X_t$ are distributed as $dX_t\sim N(0,\sin^2(t)\,dt)$ or $2\,dX_t\sim N(0,2(1-\cos(2t))\,dt)$. This means that there exists a second Brownian motion $\widetilde W$ so that
$$
X_t=X_0+\frac12\widetilde W_{2t-\sin(2t)}.
$$

Comment: It's actually an overload to call this an SDE. This equation means nothing but $X_{t}=X_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\operatorname{sin}(s)dW_{s}$.

Answer (score 3):

No; if you apply Itô's lemma to $W_t \sin t$, you won't recover your proposed dynamics.

Another way to see this is by noting that a solution of this SDE would be a martingale, since $\sin$ is square integrable. But,
$$E(X_t | \mathcal{F}_s) = W_s \sin t \neq X_s$$
showing that your proposed process cannot solve this SDE.

Comment: @Sinem does this answer your question?